# Numerical Approximation for Negative Lambert Function?

Tags: numerical-methods, lambert-w

Backpacking off my previous question, [Finding root of function, possible Lambert function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697526/finding-root-of-function-possible-lambert-function), of finding the root of the following equation:

$c_1-\frac{2}{c_2}(x+2)e^{-x/2}=0$,

Where $0<c_1\le1$ and $2<c_2<\infty$

It can be reduced into the following Lambert form:

$x=-2(1+W(\frac{-c_1c_2}{4e})$

The only problem is that on Wikipedia it states that

[image]

so The Lambert function works only if $x\ge -1/e$, but my lambert function, $W(\frac{-c_1c_2}{4e})$, where $\frac{-c_1c_2}{4e}$ can be extremely small (negative) as $c_2->\infty$, so how could I actually solve for my Lambert function then?

Comment: If your $W$ argument (in this case I think you mean $(-c_1c_2/4/e)$ is $<-1/e$ this means that the original equation has no real solutions. Try to see if you can change the conditions so that the argument becomes $>-1/e$. Lambert's $W$ function is meant to "solve" such equations in a broader ontext, which includes Complex Numbers. If the solution for all branches is complex, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: The function is multivalued, so you have to pick up a branch.

Comment: @user48672 Can you explain a little bit more? I know that it is multivalued with $c_1, c_2$, but with $c_1$ being between 0 and 1, it takes a 'percentage' of $c_2$, where $c_2$ is always greater than 2. So in that way I see it as single value.